# Problem saving photos in a view using django-imagekit

Tags: django, django-forms, django-imagekit

I'm using this code in one of my views:

```
    if request.method == 'POST':
      vehicle = VehicleForm(request.POST or None)
      photos = PhotosFormSet(request.POST or None)
      if vehicle.is_valid():
        vehicle.save()
        photos = PhotosFormSet(request.POST, instance=vehicle)
        photos.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/vehicles/')
    else:
      vehicle = VehicleForm()
      photos = PhotosFormSet(instance=Vehicle())

    return render_to_response('vehicles/vehicles-add-edit.html', 
           {'vehicle': vehicle, 'photos': photos}, 
           context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

But I get an error: `'VehicleForm' object has no attribute 'pk'` when I try to submit the form.

I've declared `PhotosFormSet` as:

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.generic import generic_inlineformset_factory
PhotosFormSet = generic_inlineformset_factory(Photo, extra=10)
```

Then my `Photo` class is as follows:

```
class Photo(ImageModel):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  original_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos')
  num_views = models.PositiveIntegerField(editable=False, default=0)
  position = models.ForeignKey(PhotoPosition)
  content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
  object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
  content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

  class IKOptions:
    spec_module = 'specs'
    cache_dir = 'photos'
    image_field = 'original_image'
    save_count_as = 'num_views'
```

Comment: Hey Stephen, I'm doing something similar and I get the same error that you were getting but for the GET method. "photos = PhotosFormSet(instance=Vehicle())" how does this line work (within the "else") if it hasn't been saved, thus not having a pk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your problem:

```
vehicle.save()
photos = PhotosFormSet(request.POST, instance=vehicle)
```

`vehicle` here is the Form, not the Vehicle object. `.save()` returns a new Vehicle, but you don't set it to a variable, so it's lost. You're then passing the form, not the new object, to the formset.

Instead, just do this:

```
new_vehicle = vehicle.save()
photos = PhotosFormSet(request.POST, instance=new_vehicle)
```